# How to pass Textfield value to view controller through button click in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, admob

I am having an issue getting my simple UI for an Admob banner to work using swiftUI and view controller.

Controller:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import GoogleMobileAds
import ToastViewSwift


public class AdsScreenViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {
   
    var auID = ""
   
    init (auID: String){
        self.auID = auID
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
   
   
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
   
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        var bannerView: GADBannerView!
       
        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

        addBannerViewToView(bannerView)

        bannerView.adUnitID = auID
        bannerView.rootViewController = self

        bannerView.load(GADRequest())

        bannerView.delegate = self

       
    }

    func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    view.addConstraints(
      [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                          attribute: .bottom,
                          relatedBy: .equal,
                          toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                          attribute: .top,
                          multiplier: 1,
                          constant: 0),
       NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                          attribute: .centerX,
                          relatedBy: .equal,
                          toItem: view,
                          attribute: .centerX,
                          multiplier: 1,
                          constant: 0)
      ])
   }

public func bannerViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
  print("bannerViewDidReceiveAd")
}

public func bannerView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error) {
  print("bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

public func bannerViewDidRecordImpression(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
  print("bannerViewDidRecordImpression")
}

public func bannerViewWillPresentScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
  print("bannerViewWillPresentScreen")
}

public func bannerViewWillDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
  print("bannerViewWillDIsmissScreen")
}

public func bannerViewDidDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
  print("bannerViewDidDismissScreen")
}

}
```

Swift UI:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit


struct TestAdsView: View {
    @State private var auID = ""
    @State private var auType = 1
    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                Text("AdUnit")
                    .font(.footnote).fontWeight(.medium)
                TextField("adunitid", text: $auID)
                    .font(.headline)
            })
            VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.auID = auID
                    }, label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Show Ad")
                        }
                    })
       
        BannerViewController(auID: auID)
 
    }
   )}
}


struct TestAdsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestAdsView()
    }
}

struct BannerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var auID: String
   
    public typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
   
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<BannerViewController>) -> BannerViewController.UIViewControllerType {
   
        return AdsScreenViewController(auID: auID)

    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: BannerViewController.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<BannerViewController>) {
       
        let controller = AdsScreenViewController(auID: auID)

        controller.auID = self.auID
    }
}
```

Everything compiles fine and it runs showing the TextView. But when entering the id it's not invoking the bannerView.load, I thought the UIViewControllerRepresentable auto updates like a listener on the view and it should be invoked but nothing is happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=swiftui%20communicate%20with%20uikit

Comment: @loremipsum been trying for two days now, trying to get it to work with Admob callbacks as well. Tried most of those links and got here. Not massively familiar with ios development, just need some guidance where this is going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Why would it? What part of your code is supposed to call `load` when the id is entered? As of now it is only called when `viewDidLoad` so you call it once with the id is blank.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be trying to replace the controller on `updateUIViewController` you `make` once and update  or call methods the rest of the times. There are many examples in SO on how to implement google ads.

Comment: if you replace `var auID: String` with `@Binding var auID: String` in `BannerViewController` you might get it to work but you will likely get flagged by Google because you will be recreating the ad too many times. Because of `let controller = AdsScreenViewController(auID: auID)` on `updateUIViewController`

Comment: Thanks but that's what I'm struggling with calling load when the Id is entered from clicking the button. If I put in the button action bannerViewController(auID:auID) it doesn't work. Can you show me how to instantiate the view controller and use it? Apologies I'm more of an adops guy with Java Android experience. Learning ios. In Java would just have the activities views etc and view listeners. Google docs doesn't show how to do it with swift ui.

Comment: Loading an ad with a `Button` is unusual the user does not know the `adUnitID` it should be built in some how. I don't have a project with Google Mobile Ads build in to provide a sample but if you use the exact code and pattern as the google example and wrap it in the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` it should work. I communicate between the 2 frameworks using a `ViewModel` that is an `ObservableObject` it is a `@StateObject` in SwiftUI that gets passed as a parameter to the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and the `UIViewController` in the `UIViewController`

Comment: The `UIViewController` can subscribe to `@Published` using `.sink` and you can hold a reference to the `UIViewController` in the `ViewModel` to call methods in it.

Comment: Thanks it's unusual but the user is entering the adunit Id through a text field. The aunitid gets assigned to auID and when the user clicks I want the banner to be shown. I can do it easily but adding load where the button is. Problem then is the delegate callback events I want to capture. Il have a go and another look at your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little sample. Like I said I don't have Google Ads in anything right now but it should be straightforward

```
import SwiftUI
struct TestAdsView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: AdsScreenViewModel = AdsScreenViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(vm.adStatus.rawValue)
            TextField("adId", text: $vm.adUnitId)
            Button("load Ads", action: {
                vm.loadAds()
            })
            //You might have to play with the position of this.
            AdsScreenView_UI(viewModel: vm).frame(width: 0, height: 0)
        }
    }
}
//This is the source of truth the user input will be held here
class AdsScreenViewModel: ObservableObject, MyAdsViewModelProtocol{
    ///reference to UIKit
    var uiViewController: MyAdsViewControllerProtocol? = nil
    
    @Published var adUnitId: String = ""
    @Published var adStatus: AdStatus = .unknown
    //MARK: MyAdsViewControllerProtocol
    func loadAds() {
        print(#function)
        uiViewController?.loadAds()
    }
    
    func setAdStatus(adStatus: AdStatus) {
        print(#function)
        self.adStatus = adStatus
    }
    func getAdId() -> String {
        print(#function)
        return adUnitId
    }
    
}
struct AdsScreenView_UI: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: AdsScreenViewModel
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some AdsScreenViewController {
        print(#function)
        return AdsScreenViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
//This can mirror the google sample
class AdsScreenViewController: UIViewController, MyAdsViewControllerProtocol {
    ///SwiftUI Delegate
    var viewModel: MyAdsViewModelProtocol
    
    init(viewModel: MyAdsViewModelProtocol) {
        print(#function)
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: .main)
        //Link between UIKit and SwiftUI
        self.viewModel.uiViewController = self
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(#function)
        viewModel.setAdStatus(adStatus: .initialized)
        //Put the current code you have here
    }
    //MARK: MyAdsViewModelProtocol
    func loadAds() {
        print(#function)
        print("ad id \(viewModel.getAdId())")
        viewModel.setAdStatus(adStatus: .loading)
        //You would load here not in viewDidLoad
    }
}
//Protocols aren't needed but it makes the code reusable and you can see the connection protocol = interface
protocol MyAdsViewModelProtocol{
    ///Reference to the google view controller
    var uiViewController: MyAdsViewControllerProtocol? { get set }
    
    ///Tells the viewController to load the ad
    func loadAds()
    ///Retrieves the AdId
    func getAdId() -> String
    ///Sets the Ad Status
    func setAdStatus(adStatus: AdStatus)
}
protocol MyAdsViewControllerProtocol: UIViewController{
    ///Reference to the SwiftUI ViewModel
    var viewModel: MyAdsViewModelProtocol { get set }
    ///Tells Google to load the ad
    func loadAds()
}
enum AdStatus: String{
    case initialized
    case loading
    case unknown
    case error
}

struct TestAdsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestAdsView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I will give this a go. Just really ill at the moment. Will likely be tomorrow on first attempt. Really appreciate it

Comment: For some reason the uiViewController?.loadAds() isn't being called in the AdsScreenViewModel class. So all that is being printed is the loadAds function from the model class.

Comment: @Sam Did u change the code? In the view controller init you have to set the uiViewController variable in the view model. Look at the comment in my code where it says “Link between UIKit and SwiftUI”

Comment: @Sam I posted a screenshot of my console after typing Abc in the textField and pressing the button to load the ads.

Comment: Thank you so much. My bad I didn't include the AdsScreenViewUI into the swift ui. I was writing it out whilst looking not copying and pasting to understand it. Just need to work out how to seperate into seperate files now and add the adtype which I will pass into your view model. Thank you again so much.

Comment: @Sam I’m glad it helped. One great thing about swift is that you can just separate them. There is not much to it. Just copy the class or struct and paste it into a new .swift file

Comment: Yep just realised. Alot better than Java for sure. Thank you