# How to know swiftUI event in UIKit view controller? || How to provide communication between swiftUI and uikit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am new to swiftUI. I want to add swiftUI view in my current UIkit project for which I created a demo in which I m stuck now.

Here is my ViewController in code :

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var stepperContenerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn:UIButton!
    
    
    lazy var stepView = StepperView(intialCount: 1)
    lazy var swiftUIHostingView = UIHostingController(rootView: stepView)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        stepperContenerView.addSubview(swiftUIHostingView.view)
        addChild(swiftUIHostingView)
//        stepView.delegate = self

        swiftUIHostingView.view.frame = stepperContenerView.bounds
        stepperContenerView.addConstrained(subview: swiftUIHostingView.view)
        swiftUIHostingView.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    @IBAction func onClickBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Stepper count", message: "Current value : \(stepView.getCount())", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } 
}
 
//extension ViewController:OnClickStepperButton {
//    func updateCount(count: Int) {
//        print("Test")
//        lbl.text = "Stepper count is - \(count)"
//    }
//}
```

and here is my code for swiftUI stepper view:-

```
import SwiftUI

protocol OnClickStepperButton {
    func updateCount(count:Int)
}

struct StepperView: View {
    @State private var count:Int = 1
    var delegate:OnClickStepperButton?
    
    init(intialCount:Int){
        self.count = intialCount
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
            Button("+", action: {
                count += 1
                print(count)
//                delegate?.updateCount(count: count)
            })
            
            Text("\(count)")
                .frame(minWidth: 40,minHeight: 40)
                .background(Color.white)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .scaledToFill()
                
            Button("-", action: {
                if count > 1 {
                    count -= 1
                    print(count)
                }
//                delegate?.updateCount(count: count)
            })
            
        }
        .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
        .frame(minWidth: 120, minHeight: 40, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(20)
    
    }
    public func getCount() -> Int {
        count
    }

}

struct Stepper_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StepperView(intialCount: 1)
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 70))
    }
}
```

Neither the delegate are calling, nor I m getting update value value on clicking of the button. (delegate are comment on purpose for highlighting its not working kindly uncomment it to check).

Comment: I might be missing it but your delegate never gets set. Remove the question mark to make sure you get an initial value

Comment: Its working now thanks 

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get update count value when I click on button(btw) in uiviewcontroller

Comment: The way you have the greyed out code now should work assuming you have a label IBOutlet you aren’t showing.

Comment: Currently I m not using that it .I added it just for demo purpose.

Comment: Can you please tell me one how can I get updated. value of count when I click on alert 

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Stepper count", message: "Current value : \(stepView.getCount())", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
```
over here

Comment: SwiftUI doesn’t work that way you can’t access its variables like that. If you create a view model that is a source of truth for the variables you can share the info between then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806) is a sample. This one if for the other way around but you should be able to see the pattern. Since yours has the hosting controller you don’t need the UIViewRepresentable from the sample.

Comment: Ok got it thanks! can you please tell me reason due to which delegate is getting nil when I m using it as optional :) if so that will be great and help me to understand the concept.

Comment: You aren’t setting it. Leaving it as an optional means they it may or may not have a value. By removing the ? You force it to have a value. If you add the ? now that you are passing the value in the initializer it should work. That value in the initializer is key without it it doesn’t know who to call.

Comment: ok got it thanks 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `delegate` Variable never gets set as is.

You need to remove the ? From the variable in the SwiftUI view so you are forced to provide a value upon init.

Also, remove the custom initializer.