# MapKit Flyover mode with bad performance when map overlays are used/rendered on the map

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

It seems that Map performance drops really hard when switching from e.g. `MKMapType.satellite` to `MKMapType.satelliteFlyover`, meaning that when flyover (3D) images are displayed on the map, this seems to be really resources-consuming.

I'm using a custom `MKOverlay` with a custom `MKOverlayRenderer` on my map that updates/renders anytime the user changes the input variable from the UI. This seems to be really laggy when a flyover map type is activated for `MKMapView`. I guess this is because the internal map structure and rendering process are a lot more complicated when displaying not only 2D satellite images but rendering 3D flyover data instead.

Did anyone of you also experience this behavior and can confirm this explanation? Am I doing anything wrong, maybe? At the moment I'm thinking about suggesting users to not use this flyover mode when also displaying the high-level custom map overlay as it lags.

```
// the wrapped map as SwiftUI component
struct TheMap: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        return MKMapView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        // called when some vars changed the overlay depends on
        if let ol = mapView.overlays.first(where: { $0 is MyCustomMKOverlay }) as? MyCustomMKOverlay {
            mapView.renderer(for: ol)?.setNeedsDisplay(mapView.visibleMapRect)
        }
    }
}

class MyCustomMKOverlay: NSObject, MKOverlay {
    // (...)
}

class MyCustomOverlayRenderer: MKOverlayRenderer {
    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
        // (...) lots of drawing on context: CGContext
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @Rob for your reply! I tested on both simulator as well as a real, powerful device. I updated my question with some simplified code. Maybe, someone came across a related problem.

Comment: Don’t use update to do that work. You are setting the overlays every time SwiftUI reloads the body. Do it with a method.

Comment: Hi @loremipsum! Thanks. Although I'm not sure if this solves the problem (as I think the map just gets too heavy with overlay data), how would you do this? In a UIViewRepresentable I only have access to my UIView inside of updateUIView. When I add a function that should be called from outside (from the SwiftUI e.g. onChange), this function has to do modifications on my MKMapView. How do I get in in that extra function. Another idea: should I add an extra Binding that informs my UIViewRepresentable that it should update overlays in updateUIView and set that boolean back to false?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I wouldn't use a `UIViewRepresentable` at all, I would use a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` then connect SwiftUI and UIKit via common class. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806), I would create the overlays on purpose vs every time update gets called. Put a `print` statement there and see how many times it gets called.