# I'm trying to convert a MSAL login from UIKit to SwiftUI and not sure how I can implement the MSALWebviewParameters into SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uiviewcontroller, uikit, azure-ad-msal

I've implemented a lot of the MSAL into SwiftUI, but I'm running into a hiccup with `MSALWebviewParameters` which needs a`UIViewController`.

This is the current code portion that works with UIKit.

```
    @objc func buttonTapped(_ snder: UIButton) {
        do {
            <Some Code that works>
            let webViewParameters = MSALWebviewParameters(authPresentationViewController: self)
            let interactiveParameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(scopes: ["user.read"], webviewParameters: webViewParameters)
            application.acquireToken(with: interactiveParameters) { (result, error) in

  }
```

What I'm trying to do is move that function into an `ObservableObject`, but these three lines depend on a `UIViewController`.  My end goal is to move this function into a `classObservableObject`

Comment: Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806). You need the UIViewController but you can manipulate the UIViewController from an ObservableObject

Comment: Thanks, let me give this a shot.

Comment: It should work follow the pattern of the loadAds method.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you @loremipsum

Comment: @loremipsum so something I'm having issues with is I'm not able to pass a variable to the Publisher.  Using your example link I'm not able to pass `adUnitId`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the publisher but the `UIViewController` can access it with `viewModel.getAdId()`, look at the `print` in the sample `loadAds()`. Something to note are the `protocol`s, if the variables/functions are not listed there the other `class` won't be able to see it. You don't need the protocols, it is just an abstraction layer but that code has them so to make more methods and variables you have to add them in the protocols first.

Comment: @Robert, any chance you can post some of the code showing how you did it?

Comment: Maybe an upvote of this request could help: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/ed66e827-c725-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789

Comment: I was also looking at generic oAuth Swift options as B2C supports oAuth2. https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift and https://github.com/p2/OAuth2

Comment: @lcj I wrote up a github post here https://github.com/arbyruns/SwiftUI-MSALSample

Comment: That's a great project. Thank you, and thank you for the help. I am trying to configure it now. I was concerned that the developer support for MSAL and SwiftUI was not great. You worked around the UIViewController piece, but ideally you would not have to.