# UIView problems in Swiftui

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to execute a function from UIViewController in SwiftUI, but i keep getting an error:

`[Presentation] Attempt to present * on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy.`

My Swift code with functions:

```
class VerifyViewController: UIViewController {
  let verifyButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Verify Identity", for: .normal)
    return button
  }()

  let activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    return activityIndicator
  }()

  let stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 8
    return stackView
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set up UI
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(activityIndicator)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(verifyButton)
    view.addSubview(stackView)

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
      stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    ])
      verifyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapVerifyButton), for: .touchUpInside)
  }
    
    @objc
    
    func topMostController() -> UIViewController? {
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController else {
            return nil
        }

        var topController = rootViewController

        while let newTopController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = newTopController
        }

        return topController
    }
    
      func didTapVerifyButton() {
        // Disable the button while the request is made
        verifyButton.isEnabled = false
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
          

        // Make request to your verification endpoint
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "***")!)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { [weak self] data, response, error in
          DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            // Re-enable button
            self?.verifyButton.isEnabled = true
            self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
              let topVC = self!.topMostController()

            guard error == nil,
                  let data = data,
                  let responseJson = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String: String].self, from: data),
                  let clientSecret = responseJson["client_secret"] else {
              // Handle error
              print(error as Any)
              return
            }

          
              topVC!.present(presentVerificationSheet(clientSecret: <#String#>), animated: true, completion: nil)
          }
        }
        task.resume()
      }

      func presentVerificationSheet(clientSecret: String) {
        // Instantiate and present the sheet
        let verificationSheet = IdentityVerificationSheet(verificationSessionClientSecret: clientSecret)
        verificationSheet.present(from: self, completion: { result in
          switch result {
          case .flowCompleted:
            // The user has completed uploading their documents.
            // Let them know that the verification is processing.
            print("Verification Flow Completed!")
          case .flowCanceled:
            // The user did not complete uploading their documents.
            // You should allow them to try again.
            print("Verification Flow Canceled!")
          case .flowFailed(let error):
            // If the flow fails, you should display the localized error
            // message to your user using error.localizedDescription
            print("Verification Flow Failed!")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
          }
        })
      }
    }
```

The way i'm trying to execute the function:

```
struct StripeButtonTest: View {
    
    @State var verification = VerifyViewController()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Show details") {
                verification.didTapVerifyButton()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried achieving this by creating *UIViewRepresentable*, but that didn't seem to work as needed.

I would be really thankful for the help!

Comment: You need a similar setup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806)

Comment: It looks like `didTapVerifyButton` has some code that would depend on the controller being on screen to execute. I think you may be better off going the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` route unless you're going to change that code. Perhaps show your attempt at that and explain what didn't work about it? Might also be import to note that a `UIView` (like you reference in your title and when you mention `UIViewRepresentable`) is not the same as a `UIViewController`, which is what you have, and is what depends on `UIViewControllerRepresentable`