# Alternate of ViewController in SwiftUI project

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, admob, google-native-ads

What is the counterpart of `ViewController` class in a project with interface of type SwiftUI?

I am following [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native/start#swift_4) to initialize `adLoader` from Google AdMob in a SwiftUI project. All examples in the document are within a `ViewController : UIViewController` class. However, I saw that `ViewController` is only available when I create a project with storyboard as the interface. But not SwiftUI. Examples in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native/start#swift_4) are initializing the `adLoader` in the following way by assignment using the keyword `self`, to parameters `rootViewController` and `adLoader.delegate`. My project was created with interface as SwiftUI and does not have a `ViewController` class. I have a main app class that implements `App` protocol with `@main` annotation. I then have a view that is being loaded from the main app class. Please help me understand what I can use in place of the keyword `self` to initialize the `adLoader` object.

**Code from the google document I am trying to work with:**

```
var adLoader: GADAdLoader!
var nativeAdView: GADNativeAdView!

adLoader = GADAdLoader(adUnitID: YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID, rootViewController: self,
        adTypes: [.native],
        options: [multipleAdsOptions])
    adLoader.delegate = self
```

Documentation for [GADAdLoader](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/api/reference/Classes/GADAdLoader)

**Sample code in project**
MyApp.swift

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {

  init() {}
  var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup{
            HomeView()
        }
   }
```

HomeView.swift

```
struct HomeView: View {
       var body: some View {
        
        customMainNavBar
        .onAppear(){
            ------
            ------
        }
    }
}
```

**Errors I get when I put this code in the View or the main App.**

- `Cannot convert value of type 'HomeView' to expected argument type 'UIViewController?'`
- `Cannot assign value of type 'HomeView' to type 'GADAdLoaderDelegate?'`
- `Cannot convert value of type 'MyApp' to expected argument type 'UIViewController?'`
- `Cannot assign value of type 'MyApp' to type 'GADAdLoaderDelegate?'`

Comment: You need something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit