# How to refresh ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Swift noob here. I have a simple app that has a main page which is a ViewController, relevant code below:

```
import SwiftUI

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    ...
    
    func updateUI() {
        switch (SettingsView().selectedBGColor) {
            case 0: self.view.backgroundColor = .black
            case 1: self.view.backgroundColor = .red
            case 2: self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
            default: break
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        updateUI()
        ...
    }
}
```

And the second page is a Settings page invoked by a UIbutton press. This page is not a ViewController, just a View. Relevant code below:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    ...
    var bgcolors = ["Black", "Red", "Blue"]
    @AppStorage("selectedBGColor") var selectedBGColor = 0
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

      var body: some View {
          NavigationView {
              Form {
                  ...
                  Section {
                      Picker(selection: $selectedBGColor, label: Text("Background color")) {
                          ForEach(0 ..< bgcolors.count, id: \.self) {
                              Text(self.bgcolors[$0]).tag($0)
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  Section {
                      Button("Save and exit", action: {
                          GameViewController().updateUI()
                          dismiss.callAsFunction()
                      }).navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"))
                  }
              }
          }
    }
}
```

When I change the selected background color in the settings and close the settings by clicking the button, the background color of the ViewController doesn't change until I relaunch the app. How do I force it to update? I tried various things I found here like `loadView()`, `setNeedsDisplay()`, `DispatchQueue`, `ViewWillAppear`/`ViewDidAppear`and `performSegue()`but nothing worked. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any special reason you need to work with both UIKit and SwiftUI?

Comment: You need a setup similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806)

Comment: How do you trigger an update? View controllers and `UIView`s are not like SwiftUI views, that can automatically re-render themselves. You should manually call an update in UIKit views.