# Save computed route/polyline consisting of many coordinates in SwiftUI for fast access

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit

I'm looking for way to save my computed polyline for fast displaying when pressing a button. At the moment it takes ages for the route to compute in the updateUIView function.

Is there a way to store my trackCoordinates and make them accessible when adding the overlay or to store the polyline itsself?

The track consists of about 900 coordinates.

```
import SwiftUI import MapKit import CoreLocation


//    MARK: ObservableObject class MapViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var didPressTrack01 = false }



struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    //    MARK: Track-Data

    
    let track01_lat = "4.0228176937071,4.022820134536,4.0228225788423"
    
    let track01_long = "4.43144629937264,4.43144455316597,4.43144281824249"
    

    var lat1 : [Double] {
        return track01_lat.components(separatedBy: ",").compactMap(CLLocationDegrees.init)
    }
    
    var lon1 : [Double] {
        return track01_long.components(separatedBy: ",").compactMap(CLLocationDegrees.init)
    }
    
    var trackCoordinates1 : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
        
        var LocationsArray = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
        for i in 0..<lat1.count {
            LocationsArray.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat1[i], longitude: lon1[i]))
        }
        return LocationsArray
    }

    //    MARK: UIRepresentable
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MapViewModel   
    @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion 
    @Binding var centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D



let map = MKMapView()

///Use class Coordinator method
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(self)
}
///Creating map view at startup
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    let map = context.coordinator.mapView
    map.setRegion(region, animated: false)
    map.showsUserLocation = true
    

    map.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    return map
}

func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    
    view.delegate = context.coordinator

    if viewModel.didPressTrack01 == true {

        let polyline1 = MKPolyline(coordinates: trackCoordinates1, count: trackCoordinates1.count)
        view.addOverlay(polyline1)
    }      
}



//MARK: - Core Location manager delegate
class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    var control: MapView

         init(_ control: MapView) {
             self.control = control
         }
    
    var mapView = MKMapView()

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if let routePolyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
            let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: routePolyline)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemRed
            renderer.lineWidth = 2
            return renderer
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
} }


// MARK: View that shows map to users struct Tap_Map_View: View {


@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:4.02281, longitude: 4.43188), latitudinalMeters: 180, longitudinalMeters: 180)
@State private var centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 4.02281, longitude: 4.43188)
@StateObject var viewModel = MapViewModel()

var body: some View {

    return ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
        MapView(viewModel: viewModel, region: $region,centerCoordinate: self.$centerCoordinate)            

        HStack{

            Spacer()

            Button {
                viewModel.didPressTrack01.toggle()
            } label: {
                Label("", systemImage: "point.topleft.down.curvedto.point.bottomright.up")
            }
            Spacer()         
    }
} }
```

Comment: Put the `MKMapView` in a `UiViewController` and then use a setup similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806)

Answer (score 1):

Usually neighboring coordinates of a polyline have a short distance from each other.

This makes it possible to compress the data very efficiently. Google defined a polyline compression that is available in many programming languages, including Swift.

I find this Swift implementation very reliable and fast:
https://github.com/raphaelmor/Polyline

This format is used by many routing servers to send polylines from server to client.