# Why is my view not updating when value is updated using @Published and @ObservedObject?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-camera

I am creating an object recognition app that takes frames from the camera and outputs a description of the image into a text view on the screen. I can print the output to the console, but cannot get the view to update with the text using the ObservableObject protocol. I have looked for solutions but none have seemed to work.

Camera View:

```
struct Analysis {
    var description: String = "No description"
    var confidence: Double = 0.0
}


final class CameraView: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    var frameCounter = 0

    @Published var analysis = Analysis()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CameraView.rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        captureSession.startRunning()

        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))

        captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)

    }

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        frameCounter += 1

        if frameCounter == 15 {

            frameCounter = 0

            guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {return}

            guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Resnet50().model) else {return}
            let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { finishedReq, err in

                guard let results = finishedReq.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else {return}

                guard let firstObservation = results.first else {return}

                self.analysis = Analysis(description: firstObservation.identifier, confidence: Double(firstObservation.confidence))


            }

            try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])

            print(self.analysis)
        }

    }

extension CameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    public typealias UIViewControllerType = CameraView

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraView>) -> CameraView {

        return CameraView()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CameraView, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraView>) {

    }
}
```

Content View:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var camera = CameraView()

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            camera
                .ignoresSafeArea()

            VStack {

                Spacer()

                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 75)
                        .background(.regularMaterial)
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                        .padding()

                    Text(camera.analysis.description)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Replace ‘@ObservedObject’ with ‘@StateObject’. The latter is used to create an instance of the view model, the former is used to receive that instance.

Comment: You need a setup similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806) your current setup doesn't work for many reasons. Starting with a `View`/`UIViewControllerRepresentable` does not work as a `class` it must be a `struct` which in turn can't be an `ObservableObject`

Comment: Another important thing to note is that every time you call `CameraView()` you create a different instance. The instance in `ContentView` is not the same as the instance in the `extension` but this doesn't take away that the root of your issues in the `class` <=> `UIViewControllerRepresentable` setup is incompatible