# Interstitial ads pops up after every X seconds

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

can anyone please help me with this. How to show interstitial ads pop out after every x seconds and the ad will run only for few seconds and go back to the Main Screen.
Currently I am using this:

This is the Banner Ad:

```
import GoogleMobileAds
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct GADBannerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 320, height: 100))
        let view = GADBannerView(adSize: adSize)
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        view.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
        view.rootViewController = viewController
        viewController.view.addSubview(view)
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: adSize.size)
        view.load(GADRequest())
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
}
```

This is the Interstitial Ad:

```
import GoogleMobileAds
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

final class Interstitial:NSObject, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
  var interstitial:GADInterstitialAd?

  override init() {
    super.init()
    self.loadInterstitial()
  }

    func loadInterstitial(){
        let request = GADRequest()
        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910",
                               request: request,
                               completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
                                if let error = error {
                                    print("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    return
                                }
                                interstitial = ad
                                interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                               })
    }

    func showAd(){
        if self.interstitial != nil {
            let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
            self.interstitial?.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
        }
        else{
            print("Not Ready")
        }
    }
    
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Ad did dismiss full screen content.")
        self.loadInterstitial()
    }
    
}
```

And this is how I am currently implementing in my View.

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMobileAds

struct AdvertView: View {
    private var fullScreenAd: Interstitial?
    init() {
        fullScreenAd = Interstitial()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 320, height: 100))

        NavigationView {
            
            Form {
              
               Button("test", action: {
                    self.fullScreenAd?.showAd()
                })
                
                
                //Banner
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    GADBannerViewController()
                        .frame(width: adSize.size.width, height: adSize.size.height)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Ad Test")
        }
        
    }
}
```

So, when I press the Test Button, the ad changes to Interstitial ad.
I want to appear the ads both Banner and Interstitial on different screens after certain timings without using the buttons. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: This isn't Swiftui

Comment: I am using it in my Swift Ui project and it works fine. However, I don't want to implement it using a button. I want it to appear after every X seconds automatically.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Should we imagine or guess how do you use this in SwiftUI code and where is the problem?

Comment: Okay, I have shared the complete files that I am using. Is that okay now?

Comment: You need a setup similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806) that way you can call `loadAds` on a `Timer`. But since you are presenting in the `rootViewController` you don't need `GADBannerViewController` it isn't doing anything. Make `Interstitial` a variable and call `loadInterstitial` whenever you want.