# Banner view does not update when @State variable changes

Tags: swift

I am trying to pass an admob(test) Id string from firebase to my BannerViewController. However, the view does not change when I modify my @State variable when executing my function. I placed a text to see the change in real time.

The variable 'theStringAd' should change to "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716" when onAppear fires my function loadAd_Chart_()

[this is what the ContentView look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFSVt.png)

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @State var theStringAd: String = "string should change"
  //theStringAd should change to "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716" when onAppear fires my function loadAd_Chart_()

    var body: some View {
     
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView{
                VStack{
                   make_ad_view(coolString: $theStringAd)
             
                    Text("The String: \(theStringAd)")

                    }
                 }
             }.onAppear{
               loadAd_Chart_()
                             }
    }

    func loadAd_Chart_() {

             Firestore.firestore().collection("chartData").document("vqzVQOEzsbbOW1j11Oc6").getDocument { (docs, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                
            
            if let documentSnapshot = docs, documentSnapshot.exists {
                print("loading")
                let ad_one_database = documentSnapshot.get("ad_one") as? String ?? ""
                theStringAd = ad_one_database
            print(theStringAd)
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
              
}
```

I know it receives the id because it prints "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

Banner View

```
struct make_ad_view: View {
    @Binding var coolString: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            BannerAdView(adUnit: $coolString, adFormat: .regularBanner)       
        }
    }
}
```

Banner controller

```
enum AdFormat {
    
    case largeBanner
    case mediumRectangle
    case adaptiveBanner
    case regularBanner
    
    var adSize: GADAdSize {
        switch self {
        case .largeBanner: return GADAdSizeLargeBanner
        case .mediumRectangle: return GADAdSizeMediumRectangle
        case .regularBanner: return GADAdSizeBanner
        case .adaptiveBanner: return
            
            GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
        }
    }
    
    var size: CGSize {
        adSize.size
    }
}

enum AdStatus {
    
    case loading
    case success
    case failure
}


final class BannerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable  {
    
    @Binding var adUnitID: String
    let adSize: GADAdSize
    @Binding var adStatus: AdStatus
    
    init( adUnitID: Binding<String>, adSize: GADAdSize, adStatus: Binding<AdStatus>) {
        self._adUnitID = adUnitID
        self.adSize = adSize
        self._adStatus = adStatus
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(bannerViewController: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        
        let view = GADBannerView(adSize: adSize)
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.adUnitID = adUnitID
        view.rootViewController = viewController
        view.load(GADRequest())
        
        viewController.view.addSubview(view)
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: adSize.size)
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, GADBannerViewDelegate {
        
        var bannerViewController: BannerViewController
        
        init(bannerViewController: BannerViewController) {
            self.bannerViewController = bannerViewController
        }
        
        func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error) {
            bannerViewController.adStatus = .failure
        }
        
        func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
          
            bannerViewController.adStatus = .success
        }
    }
}


struct BannerAdView: View {
    @Binding var adUnit: String
    let adFormat: AdFormat
    
    @State var adStatus: AdStatus = .loading
  
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if adStatus != .failure {
                
                ZStack{
                    Text("Ad")
                        .font(.title)
                        .opacity(0.5)
                    
                    BannerViewController(adUnitID: $adUnit, adSize: adFormat.adSize, adStatus: $adStatus)
                        
                    .frame(width: adFormat.size.width, height: adFormat.size.height)
                   
                    
            
                }.frame(width: adFormat.size.width, height: adFormat.size.height)
                    
                   
            }
            
        }
        
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color(.secondarySystemFill))
          
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Binding` is only for a SwiftUI View it does not work in a `class`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806

Comment: should I add `addBannerViewToView(BannerVIew) ` and is `bannerView.adUnitID = viewModel.getAdId() ` the right code? keeps saying loading

Comment: The code on that link is a working sample. It is an unusual process because there is a TextField for the ad id but it all works, just omit the text field and put in your id. Look at it closely there are a couple of lines that are very important.