# How to retrieve value from Class to textfield Swiftui

Tags: class, swiftui, textfield

This is a web browser app. I want to get the url of the current web page loaded, 'urlObservation', from the init and update the textfield of the url address bar with that string. But i'm not sure how to do it.

WebView

```
struct WebView: NSViewRepresentable {
 .........
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate,ObservableObject {
            private var viewModel: WebStateModel
            private var wkWebview = WKWebView()
            var urlObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
      

        init(_ viewModel: WebStateModel, _ wkWebview: WKWebView) {
               self.viewModel = viewModel
                self.wkWebview = WKWebView()
                self.urlObservation = wkWebview.observe(\.url, changeHandler: { (wkWebview, change) in
                            print((wkWebview.url?.absoluteString ?? "Empty"))
                        })
            
               }
......
}
```

ContentView

```
@State var webView: WebView?
@State var text = ""

.........

   //Address Bar
   TextField("Enter a URL", text: Binding(   
                    get: { text },
                    set: { text = WebStateModel.stripHttps($0) } ), onCommit: {
                        webModel.updateUrl(text)
                    })
```

Update

I've tried adding self.text inside the changeHandler to retrieve the current url change but it returns nothing

```
   class Coordinator: NSObject, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate,ObservableObject {
        private var viewModel: WebStateModel
        private var wkWebview = WKWebView()
        var urlObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
        @Published var text = ""
       
    init(_ viewModel: WebStateModel, _ wkWebview: WKWebView) {
          
            self.viewModel = viewModel
         
            self.wkWebview = WKWebView()
            super.init()
            self.urlObservation = wkWebview.observe(\.url, changeHandler: {  (wkWebview, change) in
                        print((wkWebview.url?.absoluteString ?? "Empty"))
                        self.text = ((wkWebview.url?.absoluteString ?? "Empty"))
                    })
           }
```

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806) approach

Answer (score 1):

Add the property `text` to the `webModel` shared between your `View` & `WebView` use it instead of the existing `text`, then update it where you need to. Just don't forget to mark it using `@Published`.

Comment: Hello, check my update

Comment: Since your class inherits from `NSObject`, you need to add `super.init()` after initializing `viewModel`.