# I don't want to reload webview when sheet dismiss

Tags: ios, swiftui, webview, modal-dialog

I'm trying to connect a GoBack button and a Forward button to a Webview. I've confirmed that it works fine in the webview (myWebView) which is set on the main view (myView).

In this webview, I implemented the ability to communicate(Java) with the webpage to open a sheet modal window(this is also web page).

However, the problem arises that the webview page return to goHome(reload to 1st page) whenever the modal window is dismissed (no problem when to open).

Isn't there any way to control this Reload Issue that occurs whenever the modal window dismiss?

If 'uiView.load(request)' is put something conditional on the updateUIView  part, the goBack/Forward navigation buttons will fail.

```swift
struct myView: View {
    
    @State var activeSheet: Bool = false
    .....

    var body: some View {

        let webView = myWebView(web: nil, actSheet: $activeSheet, req: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))

        VStack {
            webView
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $activeSheet) {
           anotherView(urlToLoad: urlToOpenInSheet)
        }
        .onChange(of: urlToOpenInSheet) { newValue in
             print("url changed to \(urlToOpenInSheet)!")
        }
        HStack {
             Button(action: {
                webView.goBack()
                print("goBack: \(urlToOpenInSheet)")
             }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.backward")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(alignment: .trailing)
              }.frame(alignment: .topTrailing)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 5))
             }
         }
    }


struct myWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let request: URLRequest
    var webview: WKWebView?
    
    @Binding var activeSheet: Bool

    init(web: WKWebView?, actSheet: Binding<Bool>, req: URLRequest) {
        self.webview = WKWebView()
        self._activeSheet = actSheet
        self.request = req
    }
    ....
    ....
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
    func goBack(){
        webView?.goBack()
    }
    func goForward(){
        webView?.goForward()
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: You need something more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I gave it up… could never control to navigate because of click event Jquery in webview…