# Swift ML Vision - Help understanding how to update an Environment array from UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate extension

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using machine learning models to detect items that come onto the preview. My goal is to setup a global array and update that array with items if they do not already exist in there. Since my function that is doing the detecting is in an extension, I'm not sure how to go about updating the array from there.

This is how I currently have setup my Environment array:

ScannedItems

```
class ScannedItems: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [String] = []
}
```

ContentView

```
        WindowGroup {
            Group {
                HomeView()
            }
            .environmentObject(ScannedItems())
        }
```

CaptureViewController

```
class CaptureViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {    
    private var permissionGranted: Bool = false
    private let captureSession: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private let sessionQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "sessionQueue")
    private var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
    
    private var videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    var requests = [VNRequest]()
    var detectionLayer: CALayer! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        ...
    }
    
    func checkPermission() {
        ...
    }
    
    func requestPermission() {
        ...
    }
    
    func setupCaptureSession() {
        ...
    }
}

struct CaptureViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return CaptureViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Detector - The `extractDetections` function is where I want to use my global array and add into that array if the item's label does not exist already.

```
extension CaptureViewController {
    func setupDetector() {
        ...
    }

    func detectionDidComplete(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        ...
    }

    func extractDetections(_ results: [VNObservation]) {
        for observation in results where observation is VNRecognizedObjectObservation {
            guard let objectObservation = observation as? VNRecognizedObjectObservation else { continue }
            
            let objectName = objectObservation.labels.first?.identifier ?? ""

            // IF OBJECTNAME !EXISTS IN ARRAY AND != "" ADD TO GLOBAL ARRAY

        }
    }

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is as far as I'm getting. I do not know what the proper way of adding to this list is from the extension I've made. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: hmm at the minimum you need a reference to `ScannedItems()` you are creating in ContentView to be able to update it. once there's a reference, I see no issue with updating it. Unless I don't understand your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass Textfield value to view controller through button click in Swift UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui)

Comment: So I was able to solve this by setting up the init to take in my Environment class as an argument. From there I was able to tap into the array and make modifications to it like appending the data.

Comment: If you found a solution, you can answer your own question and accept the answer. This might help others in future.