# Is there a way to add a Gesture inside .onAppear() in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop, annotations, uigesturerecognizer

I have a tricky problem and I hope someone can help me out here:
I have a container that shows a PDF and I add an Annotation to that PDF.
So far so good. Now I need that Annotation to be draggable.

First I wanted to handle that with UIPanGestureRecognizer.
That doesn't work, because it needs an @objc function and I cannot put @objc in front of a function inside of a struct, which I need for the view ('cause SwiftUI)..

```
let dragAnnotation = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggedAnnotation(sender:)))
...
// doesn't work with struct
@objc func draggedAnnotation(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
```

Second approach was a DragGesture, which would be perfect for SwiftUI, but I don't know how to add it inside the .onAppear method.

```
var body: some View {
            DocViewPDF(doc: self.pdfContainer.document)
        .onAppear {
        ...
        //doesn't work => gesture not gestureRecognizer
        annotation.addGestureRecognizer(dragAnnotation) 
        }
}
```

I need to do it in .onAppear, because the parameters are given there.
Is there a way to add the DragGesture without .gesture maybe?
Or any other way to handle this problem?

Edit: I made it work (more or less) like this:
(new problem: the dragging feels weird; the finger/mouse moves faster than the dragged object)

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

struct WelcomeView: View {
    @State private var pdfContainer: PDFView
    private var annotationImage: UIImage? // should be @State but can't be

    @State private var selectedAnnotation: PDFAnnotation?
@State var initalBounds: CGRect? = nil

    init(annotationImage: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "testSig.png")) {
        self.pdfContainer = PDFView()
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Test05", withExtension: "pdf") {
            pdfContainer.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
        }
        pdfContainer.autoScales = true
        self. annotationImage = UIImage(named: "testSig.png")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DocViewPDF(doc: self.pdfContainer.document).gesture(DragGesture().onChanged { g in
            guard let page = pdfContainer.currentPage else { return }
            guard let annotation = imageAnnotation else { return }
            if initalBounds == nil {
                initalBounds = annotation.bounds
            }
            let newX = initalBounds!.minX + g.translation.width
            let newY = initalBounds!.minY - g.translation.height
            annotation.bounds = CGRect(x: newX, y: newY, width: 200, height: 100)
        }.onEnded { _ in
            initalBounds = nil
        }).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            Button("Add Annotation") {}
        }
        .onAppear {
            guard let annImage = annotationImage
            else { fatalError(Exception.kParameterMissing.localizedDescription) }
            guard let page = pdfContainer.currentPage
            else { fatalError(Exception.kFileIsEmpty.localizedDescription) }

            // place signature-draggable in center of currentPage
            let pageBoundaries: CGRect = page.bounds(for: .cropBox)
            let imageBoundaries: CGRect = .init(x: pageBoundaries.midX, y: pageBoundaries.midY, width: 200, height: 100)
            imageAnnotation = .init(image: sigImage, bounds: imageBoundaries, properties: nil)
            page.addAnnotation(imageAnnotation)
        }
    }

class ImageAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {
    private let image: UIImage

    // A custom init that sets the type to Stamp on default and assigns our image variable
    init(image: UIImage, bounds: CGRect, properties: [AnyHashable: Any]?) {
        self.image = image
        super.init(bounds: bounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.stamp, withProperties: properties)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("required by PDFAnnotation - not needed for Image")
    }

    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
        // Get the CGImage of our image
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return }
        // Draw our CGImage in the context of our PDFAnnotation bounds
        context.draw(cgImage, in: bounds)
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to separate you UIKit code from SwiftUI. Annotation give me the impression that it is some UIKit View, SwiftUIs DragGesture wouldn’t work. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: It's a PDF Annotation, it's part of the PDFKit import (like FormFields, Inks, Texts, etc that you can add to a PDF Document)

I edited the above post and put in an example code. Problem should be easy to grasp with that. I'd appreciate any help that I can get! Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806

Comment: Thank you for the link. If I am correct you suggested to have an extra class in which I put my @objc method. I didn't manage to make that work, because both the class and the struct needed to update variables of each other.

Instead I did something else, which I'll added in above post real quick.
Got a new problem with this solution though..

Comment: Use the shared source of truth for that. I am not going to reinvent the wheel, it is always best to separate the Frameworks.